# Live Preview on extended monitor

Tags: windows, gratis, multi-monitor

I will connect two screens in my laptop with HDMI and the second screen will not be in a view angle. So, I want to have a live preview on my main monitor of what the second screen shows.

Windows has a similar feature when you hover the mouse on a tab in start menu. A little window with a live preview. I was thinking a the same thing but without need the hover.

I need it for Windows and it should be free.